# Windows Phone 7: app doesn't save PDF file download from URL in Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, webclient, isolatedstorage

I'm developing an app to manage PDF files (not a PDF-viewer), and I have a dedicate page to download PDF files with specific URL.

My problem is that the app doesn't save downloaded documents.

This is my app-code (in the page-class named PDFurl.xaml.cs):

```
private void Start_Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient PDFdownloader = new WebClient();
        DownloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        PDFdownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(PDFdownloader_DownloadProgressChanged);
        PDFdownloader.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(PDFdownloader_OpenReadCompleted);
        PDFdownloader.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(UrlText.Text));
    }

    void PDFdownloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DownloadProgress.Value = e.BytesReceived;
            DownloadProgress.Maximum = e.TotalBytesToReceive;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Download failed!");
        }
    }

    void PDFdownloader_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        string[] fileNames = storage.GetFileNames();
        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            if (fileName == (SavedFile.Text + ".pdf"))    //Save existing file
            {    
                MessageBoxResult rewrite = MessageBox.Show("Already exists a file with this name. Do you want to overwrite it?", "PDF name already used", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (rewrite == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    storage.DeleteFile(SavedFile.Text + "pdf");
                    Save_File(e);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Document not saved!");
                    e.Result.Close();
                    DownloadProgress.Value = 0;
                    DownloadProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else       //Save new file
            {
                Save_File(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Save_File(OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(SavedFile.Text + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, storage))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("File downloaded and saved successfully!");
            foreach (string file in storage.GetFileNames())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found " + file);
            }
        }   
    }
```

I included some messagebox to monitor every task, but when it show message of successfull download, it doesn't save really anything.

Comment: how do you know the PDF isn't being saved? have you examined the Isolated Storage with something like [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/). Also, are you closing the `stream` properly after writing?

Comment: Infact I know if it saved files using Isolated Storage Explorer extension of VS 2010/12. I only find the Shared directory, and I can't also find them in thi directory (and other subdir included). For stream question, I believe that's correct, I used the same part of codes of Save_Files() function in other experiment' apps for saving process and worked well...I cannot understand why in this application doesn't work, maybe I can't save PDF files using binary data method?